# How to use php custom function in opencart twig file?

Tags: php, function, twig, opencart

I am currently trying to add some code to Twig file that I already use with PHP.  I don't know how to use `mim_sub_options`. Could you please help me.

```php
<?php
    function mim_sub_options($passed_value, $parent_key, $labels, $level = 0) {
      extract($labels);

      $option_row = 0;
      $option_value_row = 0;

      foreach($passed_product_option_value['product_option'] as $product_option) {
        $final_parent_option_key = $parent_option_key . '[product_option][' . $option_row . ']';
    }

    if( ! empty($option_value['product_option'])) { 
        mim_sub_options($option_value, $option_value['product_option_value_id'], $labels);
    } 
?>
```

---

*edit*

This is my `twig.php`

```
$this->twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
        foreach(array('is_array','array_push','in_array','var_dump','addslashes','json_encode','json_decode','sizeof','count','strtotime','html_entity_decode','strtolower','is_null','array_chunk','ceil','preg_match','str_replace','preg_replace','urlencode','sprintf', 'mim_sub_options', 'extract') as $func_name){
            $this->twig->addFunction($func_name, new \Twig_Function_Function($func_name));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your function inside `opencart-storage/modification/system/library/template/twig.php`

```
//applies when min_sub_options is a global function
$this->twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('mim_sub_options', 'mim_sub_options');
```

---

Alternative example

```html
$this->twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('mim_sub_options', function($passed_value, $parent_key, $labels, $level = 0) {
    extract($labels);

    $option_row = 0;
    $option_value_row = 0;

    foreach($passed_product_option_value['product_option'] as $product_option) {
        $final_parent_option_key = $parent_option_key . '[product_option][' . $option_row . ']';
    }

    if( ! empty($option_value['product_option'])) { 
        mim_sub_options($option_value, $option_value['product_option_value_id'], $labels);
    }
}));
```